# I can't rotate my page from existing PDF

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I've just made a simple Java Console Project, which writes content to an existent PDF, but I can't rotate the page. I've already tried to rotate the **page** trying many examples found here on stackoverflow, but nothing works for me.

**My Class**

```
public class PDfRotate{

    private static String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    private static String FILERIN = workingDir + "/Rin.pdf";
    private static String FILERIN_INPUT = workingDir + "/Test.pdf";
    private static String FILERIN_OUTPUT = workingDir + "/RinOutput.pdf";
    private static Document document;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {

        Document document = new Document();
        rotatePdf(document);
        document.close();               
    }

    public static void rotatePdf(Document document) throws DocumentException, IOException{

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(FILERIN_OUTPUT));

        document.open();
        Paragraph par = new Paragraph("hello");
        document.add(par);

        document.add(PageSize.A4.rotate());

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(FILERIN);
        PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader,1);
        Image instance = Image.getInstance(page);
        document.add(instance);
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using `PdfWriter` and `Document`? If you have read the documentation, you know that this is completely wrong. Why aren't you using `PdfStamper` to add content?

Comment: Because i found that on itext developer site, and works

Comment: Show me the page on the developer site that says this is the correct way to do it? Seems to me that you want to [add a watermark](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/stamping-content-existing-pdfs/watermark-examples) to an existing page. If you want to rotate pages in an existing PDF, you should read the answer to the question [How to rotate a page 90 degrees?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-rotate-page-90-degrees)

Comment: `document.add(PageSize.A4.rotate());` ??? You want to add an  A4 sized rectangle rotated to landscape to the document?

Comment: Also, please clarify: do you want to rotate the page? Do you want to preserve the orientation of the page and add content that is rotated? Your requirement isn't clear at all.

Comment: @mkl no i want to rotates my page to horizontal.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Don't say so, that may make people hack the site and add it somewhere! ;)))

Comment: @BrunoLowagie my content shouldn't change rotation, only my page

Comment: @Dhn So you want to rotate the content already existing on a page? Or you want to add new content with rotation while leaving the original content as is? And do you want to rotate by a multiple of 90° or by some custom angle?

Comment: *i want to rotates my page to horizontal* - Ah, ok, rotating existing content by 90° that is.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie this is the page. http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-1

Comment: @Dhn I know that page. I wrote the book the examples refer to. Are you seriously saying that you took your code from those examples? If so, I can only assume that you're making fun of me. Why should I help someone who makes fun of me?

Comment: I don't SPAM. You should improve your question by explaining in clear words what you're trying to do. You should not offend me by referring to the documentation I wrote out of context. I don't doubt that the answer to your question is on the official web site.

Comment: @Dhn Bruno has a point. I concluded from your comment *i want to rotates my page to horizontal* here that you want to *rotate existing content by 90°* while your question sounds different and confuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved by myself**.

I should set the rotation before opening the document.

```
document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4.rotate());
document.open();
....
document.close();
```

Comment: That wasn't your question. You were talking about an existent PDF. You shouldn't use `PdfWriter` and `Document` when working with existent PDFs.

Comment: Ok, so tell me how i should do this. @BrunoLowagie
Mkl says me that was so difficult, rotate the page without rotate the content because  PDF is not a format that can easily be reflowed because it does not have a notion of paragraphs or anchored images, its just stuff drawn on a canvas of which a window is shown..

Comment: If you want to rotate an existing page and you want the content to reflow, then you are asking something that is almost impossible in PDF (in general, not limited to iText). You posted an answer claiming that it solved your problem. If that answer solves your problem, then your question is wrong. If your question is right, then your solution doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Dhn Your answer indicates that your problem is not about an existing PDF which you wanted to change but instead about a new one you merely did not know how to set the desired page dimensions for. If that was indeed your problem, it's good you solved it, but your question and comments did not describe that problem at all.

Comment: So, you just said that it is almost impossible in Pdf... then i decided to read my old document, make another new document and paste my old document inside it as image. @BrunoLowagie

Comment: i wanted make that, but you told me that was almost impossible. What should i do? I changed my idea, and i made a new document @mkl

Comment: It is *extremely difficult* if you want to *reflow the text*. If you merely want to take the original pages as they are and scale them down to fit the other orientation with very broad margins on two sides, that is not difficult.,

Comment: *I changed my idea, and i made a new document* - Changing one's idea is completely ok. They changed idea merely is not an appropriate answer to the original question.

Comment: That's why I kept asking to clarify the question. Pasting an existing document into a new document as an image can't be what the employer of @Dhn wants.

Comment: i can't have broad margin, because i must fill all the page from the left to the right horizzontally @mkl

Comment: I agree on you @BrunoLowagie but i don't find another way to do this, without have too much problem with reflow the text. If you find them, please tell me .

Comment: *i can't have broad margin, because i must fill all the page from the left to the right horizzontally* - and how does your answer solve that issue?

Comment: because my old document was horizontal.

Comment: *because my old document was horizontal.* - ah, and you added new content above or below to fill gaps? Sigh, you withheld so much information required to understand your use case, it really is no wonderwe all the time talked past each other...

Answer (score 3):

### Rotating the pages by 90°

At first I understood the question and comments to be about rotating the document pages (including their content) by 90°.

This is demonstrated in the iText sample [RotatePages.java](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-13#499-rotatepages.java) from chapter 13 of [iText in Action - Second Edition](http://developers.itextpdf.com/books#iia2nd). The focal code:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(SOURCE);
int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
int rot;
PdfDictionary pageDict;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    rot = reader.getPageRotation(i);
    pageDict = reader.getPageN(i);
    pageDict.put(PdfName.ROTATE, new PdfNumber(rot + 90));
}
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(RESULT));
stamper.close();
reader.close();
```

To this the OP commented that he didn't *want rotate the content, only the page.* Thus:

### Switching portrait to landscape and vice versa

To switch between landscape and portrait one can do something like the following:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(SOURCE);
int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
PdfDictionary pageDict;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    Rectangle rect = reader.getPageSize(i);
    Rectangle crop = reader.getCropBox(i);
    pageDict = reader.getPageN(i);
    pageDict.put(PdfName.MEDIABOX, new PdfArray(new float[] {rect.getBottom(), rect.getLeft(), rect.getTop(), rect.getRight()}));
    pageDict.put(PdfName.CROPBOX, new PdfArray(new float[] {crop.getBottom(), crop.getLeft(), crop.getTop(), crop.getRight()}));
}
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(RESULT));
stamper.close();
reader.close();
```

*([SwitchPageCanvas](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/content/SwitchPageCanvas.java))*

This obviously will cut away some content.

Comment: This works, but i don't want rotate the content, only my page.

Comment: @Dhn Huh? Which content? The content you are adding? You have to be more clear! There are different ways to rotate content. Tell us *exactly* what you want. As I already said, the answer is probably available in the documentation.

Comment: I've just write i **DON'T WANT ROTATE THE CONTENT** Only the **page** @BrunoLowagie

Comment: Do you mean you have an A4 portrait file and want to make it an A4 landscape file but the content shall remain upright? And probably even reflow to fill the whole width? And move to the next page if it does not fit on the original page anymore?

Comment: Yes, but I would be happy , if I could make it for Horizontal Any excesses of the text , they will manage after @mkl

Comment: **A** *Yes* - that is extremely difficult, PDF is not a format that can easily be reflowed because it does not have a notion of paragraphs or anchored images, its just stuff drawn on a canvas of which a window is shown. **B** *make it for Horizontal Any excesses of the text , they will manage after* - I don't understand what you mean.